# How to use a Microsoft Access Database file in python and SQL

Tags: python, sql

I've been struggling for hours now trying to figure out how to connect the database and then use it. I've come so far to connect it but as soon as I want to execute a 'select', it shows the error that the file is not a database even tho I made the file in MS Access and then renamed the file to .db . Here is the code, the database name is TestDB.

```
import sqlite3 as db
from sqlite3 import Error

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = db.connect(db_file)
        print(db.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            print('Got connected')
            dbCursor= conn.cursor()
            dbCursor.execute('select * from Table1')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        create_connection(r"TestDB.db")
```

Comment: Did you just rename an access file to .db, or did you export it from access to a sqlite3 database?

Comment: just renamed id to .db, i tried it as the. accdb and it also didn't work. At school we used delphi and just renaming the file from the. accdb to .db worked fine. If it is not possible to do it like this how would I export a database file with sqlite3?

Comment: I don't think you could load an mdb file into sqlite without actually converting the file format.

Comment: How do I convert the file format and to what type of file do I format it to?

Answer (score 0):

I work with mdb files a lot at work, this is my implementation:

```py
import pyodbc
DRIVER="{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}"

con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={}'.format(DRIVER,'path/to/accessfile'))
mdbcon = con.connect()
cursor = mdbcon.cursor()
```

What you put in `DRIVER` varies depending on whats installed. Check your ODBC drivers to see which one you have installed. It's also *very important* that your python installation and your access installation are both either 32-bit or 64-bit, mismatching has given me a lot of problems in the past.